# which NFS implementation is safe for sqlite database accessed by multiple processes

Tags: c++, sqlite

[here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) mentioned that "...But use caution: this locking mechanism might not work correctly if the database file is kept on an NFS filesystem. This is because fcntl() file locking is broken on many NFS implementations. You should avoid putting SQLite database files on NFS if multiple processes might try to access the file at the same time..."

But the document doesn't mention which NFS implementation works well on this. Any suggestions? What about sqlite3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locking with `fcntl` works with both NFS versions 3 and 4. As long as you can mount with `vers=3` or `vers=4`, you should be set. You can also use [`locktests`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/locktests/) to verify that locking works, and `nfsstat` to verify the available versions on the client and server.

Comment: thanks for the info. btw just use "nfsstat -m" to check NFS versions

Comment: Hi, I encountered this bug https://github.com/optuna/optuna/issues/815 on a system with `vers=3` (according to `nfsstat -m`)